# Javascript: Split String but only use 1 result

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

so i have this array:`["bilder/test/_PRF6367.JPG.jpg", "bilder/test/_PRF6372.JPG.jpg", "bilder/test/_PRF6374.JPG.jpg"]`
how do i split the individial strings JUST into  _PRF6367.JPG.jpg etc.

Comment: What would result look like, a new array?

Comment: This is pretty *basic*. You'd have more chance of getting an answer if you show what you've tried. **Edit:** I was wrong.

Comment: i tried split by '/' but then i get 3 strings but i only need the image name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create new array of modified strings:

```
["bilder/test/_PRF6367.JPG.jpg", "bilder/test/_PRF6372.JPG.jpg", "bilder/test/_PRF6374.JPG.jpg"].map(function(str) {
    return str.split('/').pop();
});
```

Result:

```
["_PRF6367.JPG.jpg", "_PRF6372.JPG.jpg", "_PRF6374.JPG.jpg"]
```